# Why is this Xpath Query not working on the DOM of facebook application pages?

Tags: php, facebook, dom, href, xpath

I dont understand why my xpath query returns the correct href for the second url but not the first url. The HTML code looks the same. It contains the same kind of structure. But somehow no href is returned. (I just comment out each one of the $url's to test it)

```
$url = "http://apps.facebook.com/TexasHoldEmPoker/"; // this one does not work
//$url = "http://nu.nl"; // this one works

$response = wp_remote_get($url);
$data = $response['body'];
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$href='';
if (!$dom->loadHTML($data))
{
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error)
    {
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
else
{
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $elements = $xpath->query("/html/head/link[@rel='shortcut icon']");

    if (!is_null($elements))
    {
        foreach ($elements as $element)
        {
            if ($element->getAttribute('href'))
            {
                $href = $element->getAttribute('href');
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $href;
```

So I know the code is working correct for "nu.nl" but somehow not for the facebook apps pages. I cant grasp why since the structure is the same.

p.s. : full code here: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-favicons/trunk/plugins/sources/page.php

Comment: As both pages are XHTML, have you tried using `DOMDocument::loadXML()` instead of `loadHTML()`?

Comment: when i try loadxml none of the 2 work. However I begin to suspect i need to play with namespaces but all attempts fail.

Comment: So $xmlding = new SimpleXMLElement($dom->saveXML()); with the same query does instead show nothing for both cases

Comment: Have you tried saving the HTML source locally, and then parsing it?  Facebook returns different responses depending on user agent - if you hit that page with wget for example, you'll get a page with the title "Incompatible Browser".  That page does have a shortcut icon set, but it's quite possible there's something else weird in the return value that your script is seeing but you're not seeing in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `$dom->saveXML()` .

You'll see that the `<link>`-element is a child of **body**, not of **head** like expected.

So the xpath should be:

```
/html/body/link[@rel='shortcut icon']
```

or

```
//link[@rel='shortcut icon']
```

I guess the different markup is a result of the parser when trying to fix the illegal `<noscript>` inside the `<head>`(everything inside the head after and including this `<noscript>` has been moved to the `<body>`)

Comment: this IS weird, when I do "view source" of the page I clearly see the link in the HEAD of the facebook app page but apparently something weird happens here. thanks!! (i'll link this in the code as above so you get the credit)

Comment: `//link[translate(@rel,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ='shortcut icon']`